# VACUUM not reclaiming space in postgres 14.7

Tags: postgresql, amazon-aurora

I have followed Laurenz excellent page here
https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/reasons-why-vacuum-wont-remove-dead-rows/

I am at my wits end. I have a heavily used table whose performance degrades everyday on postgreSQL Aurora.

Even after shutting the application that uses the table down, i am unable to reduce the space which is now around 200 MB+. The table has only 400 odd rows. This is the vaccuum verbose output. We have 2 RDS read replicas attached to the AWS postgreSQL Aurora database. No matter what i do (kill idle transactions etc.), it doesnt seem to reduce and it says nonremovable row versions.

INFO:  vacuuming "staging.sd3"
INFO:  "seq": found 0 removable, 349255 nonremovable row versions in 31735 pages
DETAIL:  348974 dead row versions cannot be removed yet.
CPU: user: 0.75 s, system: 0.06 s, elapsed: 3.19 s.

Comment: Have you done a `vacuum full`?

Comment: You need to re-read this section *Why won’t VACUUM remove the dead rows?* from the blog post. Best bet is you have one of those conditions preventing the VACUUM recycling rows.

Comment: I ran all those queries. And i did a VACUUM FULL. Issue is with AWS support now

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Aurora 14.7, try upgrading to [14.7.4 minor version](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraPostgreSQLReleaseNotes/AuroraPostgreSQL.Updates.html#AuroraPostgreSQL.Updates.20180305.1474). I ran into a similar issue. The dead rows not getting removed. After talking with AWS support, they recommended applying that fix. It solved my issue